# Node.js - Functions with same name in controller and service, best practice?

Tags: node.js, fastify

I've been using Node.js and Fastify for a few weeks now and I'm still trying to get to grips with some best practices. I come from a PHP/Laravel background.

I've broken my project down into routes, controllers and services (what would typically be models in Laravel).

I've discovered that using the same function name in the controller and service is causing an issue as the code appears to be executing the function in the service file as opposed to the controller.

How is this problem typically handled without using different function names?

**Router - /router/transactions.js**

```
function routes(fastify, options, done) {

    fastify.register(require('@fastify/formbody'))
    fastify.register(require('../controllers/transactions'))

    fastify.post('/get-initial-transaction', (req, rep) => {
        getInitialTransaction(req.body, rep)
    })

    done()
}

module.exports = routes
```

**Controller - /controllers/transactions.js**

```
controller = (fastify, options, done) => {

    const service = fastify.register(require('../services/transactions'))

    getInitialTransaction = (req, rep) => {  
        rep.send(getInitialTransaction(req.uuid));
    }

    done()
}

module.exports = controller
```

**Service - /services/transactions.js**

```
const service = (fastify, options, done) => {

    getInitialTransaction = (uuid) => {
        fastify.mysql.query(
            `SELECT t.amount, t.currency, t.reference, m.name
            FROM transactions t
            JOIN merchants m 
            ON m.id = t.merchant_id
            WHERE t.uuid = :uuid
            AND t.status_desc = "INITIAL"`, { uuid: uuid },
            function onResult(err, result) {
                if (!err) {
                    return (result[0])
                }
                else {
                    return (err)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    done()
}

module.exports = service
```

Comment: I don't understand... If that's all the code there is in your router file, getInitialTransaction would be undefined... Are you showing everything?

Comment: getInitialTransaction() in the router file is calling the getInitialTransaction() function in the controller but the problem arises due to the fact the service file also contains a getInitialTransaction() function which fundamentally means, the controller has two getInitialTransaction().

Comment: How do you load those file? I think you are using some global variables setting them after the require. Don't use global variables

Comment: @Dally I think you are not interpreting correctly. There has to be some code you are not showing. In the router file, getInitialTransaction should be undefined. Also, in your controller you define a function named getInitialTransaction that calls itself, this also would seem wrong.  Also, looking everywhere fastify doesn't seem to work much with services at all, most queries are done directly inside routes that looks weird.

Comment: Hi guys, apologies I should have been clearer in my original post. I have 3 files all named "transactions.js". One in the router folder, the other in the controllers folder and the 3rd in the services folder. I have solved this by turning the service into a class. I will be posting my solution and would appreciate some feedback on the design pattern I've used.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've managed to solve my issue. Again, I'm new to Node.js & Fastify so would appreciate feedback on the design pattern I've used.

**File Structure:**

- config

  - env.js
  - mysql.js
- controllers

  - transaction.js
- routes

  - transactions.js
- services

  - transaction.js
- server.js

**routes/transactions.js**

```
function routes(fastify, options, done) {

    fastify.register(require('@fastify/formbody'))
    fastify.register(require('../controllers/transactions'))

    fastify.get('/get-transactions', (req, rep) => {
        getTransactions(req, rep)
    })

    fastify.post('/get-initial-transaction', (req, rep) => {
        getInitialTransaction(req.body, rep)
    })

    fastify.post('/create-transaction', (req, rep) => {
        createTransaction(req, rep)
    })

    done()
}

module.exports = routes
```

**controllers/transactions.js**

```
controller = (fastify, options, done) => {

    const transaction = require('../services/transactions')
    const service = new transaction(fastify)

    getTransactions = async (req, rep) => {
        rep.send(await service.getTransactions())
    }

    getInitialTransaction = async (req, rep) => {
        rep.send(await service.getInitialTransaction(req.uuid));
        await service.updateTransactionStatusDesc(req.uuid, 'OPEN');
    }

    done()
}

module.exports = controller
```

**services/transactions.js**

```
class transaction {

    constructor(fastify) {
        this.fastify = fastify
    }

    getTransactions = async () => {

        const connection = await this.fastify.mysql.getConnection()
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.query(
            `SELECT * FROM transactions`,
        )
        connection.release()
        return rows
    }

    getInitialTransaction = async (uuid) => {

        const connection = await this.fastify.mysql.getConnection()
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.query(
            `SELECT t.amount, t.currency, t.reference, m.name
            FROM transactions t
            JOIN merchants m 
            ON m.id = t.merchant_id
            WHERE t.uuid = :uuid
            AND t.status_desc = "INITIAL"`, { uuid: uuid }
        )
        connection.release()
        return rows[0]
    }

    updateTransactionStatusDesc = async (uuid, statusDesc) => {

        const connection = await this.fastify.mysql.getConnection()
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.query(
            `UPDATE transactions SET status_desc = :statusDesc WHERE uuid = :uuid`, { uuid: uuid, statusDesc: statusDesc },
        )
        connection.release()
        console.log(rows)
        // return rows[0]
    }
}

module.exports = transaction
```